# Shutting down derby Network server doesnt delete db.lck

Tags: java, database, derby

I'm trying to start Derby in Network server mode from my Java application with default port. Server starts successfully. Now I attempt to connect to a DB called 'myDB' on the server. The connection is established and db.lck gets successfully created. I, then, do a couple of transactions, commit and close the connection, gracefully. I see that db.lck is still there. Then I shutdown the network server. I expect db.lck file deleted at the end of all these operations. But it stays. (PS: OS is Windows)

Following is the code:

1) Start the server:

```
System.setProperty("derby.system.home", "C:\\SI\\testDerby");
System.setProperty("derby.drda.traceDirectory", "C:\\SI\\trace");
System.setProperty("derby.drda.traceAll", "true");
System.setProperty("derby.drda.logConnections", "true");
System.setProperty("derby.connection.requireAuthentication", "false");

serverHandle = new NetworkServerControl();
// Write server console messages to system output
serverHandle.start(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

2) Connecting to DB

```
final String PORT = 1527;
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
String dbName = "myDB";
String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + "//localhost:" 
            + PORT  + "/" + dbName + ";create=true";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
boolean success = stmt.execute("DROP TABLE USERS");
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE USERS (id BIGINT not null, name VARCHAR(20))");
success = statement.execute();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

3) Shutting down server

```
serverHandle.shutdown();
```

Can anyone please help me out with this ? I need the db.lck file to be deleted when I close the connection or shutdown the DB. I think I'm missing something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps shutting down the server is not shutting down the database; try doing an explicit database shutdown prior to shutting down the server, as described here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/tdevdvlp40464.html#tdevdvlp40464

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the method of shutting down the database mentioned in the URL is solely for an embedded derby and not for Network server. I tried the same with Network server (that is, calling getConnection with ";shutdown=true" appended to the URL). I hit an SQLNonTransientConnectionException with following as root cause: 
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException
DERBY SQL error: SQLCODE: -1, SQLSTATE: 08006, SQLERRMC: Database 'myDB' shutdown.

Comment: But yes, the lock file in this case did get deleted. Any idea why it throws an exception here ?

Comment: That's just the way Derby behaves. Shutting down the database throws an exception. It's a bit awkward, but the SQLSTATE is pretty identifiable so I recommend you simply catch and ignore that exception.